# Python - Convert string to CamelCase

Tags: python, camelcasing

I coded the following method to convert a string to Camel Case. However, it doesn't work when the string starts with a space.

```
def CamelCase(s):
 
  newString = ''
  newString += s[0].upper()

  for k in range(1, len(s)): 
    if s[k] == ' ':
      newString += s[k + 1].upper()
      k += 1
    elif s[k - 1] != ' ':
      newString += s[k]
  return newString
```

The input is: `"  I love   chocolate."`
And the output should be: `"ILoveChocolate."`

But it gives the following error:

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-28f7ddba2ba2> in <module>
----> 1 print(CamelCase("  Algoritmos y    estructuras de   datos   "))

<ipython-input-12-29aa8012fb61> in CamelCase(s)
      9     for k in range(1, len(s)):
     10       if s[k] == ' ':
---> 11         nuevaCadena += s[k + 1].upper()
     12         k += 1
     13       elif s[k - 1] != ' ':

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Help?

Comment: Then remove the spaces at the start first?

Answer (score 3):

The string built-in function *title()* will help here:

```
def camelcase(s):
    return ''.join(t.title() for t in s.split())
```

Note that the first character in the returned string will be uppercase hence the value is upper camelcase (a.k.a. Pascal case) as opposed to the more common lower camelcase

Comment: A slightly variation, `s.title().replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating `k` from `1` to the length of the string minus one. `s[k+1]` will therefore be out of bounds.

You'll want to do a few things:

1. Use `split` to get a list of words. `s.split()`
2. Use a generator expression to capitalize each string. `re.sub(r'^[a-z]', lambda m: m.group(0).upper(), w) for w in s.split())`
3. Join this whole thing together into a string. `''.join(re.sub(r'^[a-z]', lambda m: m.group(0).upper(), w) for w in s.split())`

```
>>> s = "  I love chocolate "
>>> ''.join(re.sub(r'^[a-z]', lambda m: m.group(0).upper(), w) for w in s.split())
'ILoveChocolate'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with conversion to list and back word by word and use a capitalize method. The closet syntax to the source example is:

```
def CamelCase(s):
 
    newString = ''
    
    for word in s.split(): 
      newString += element.capitalize()
    return newString
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove extra spaces using `string.**strip()**` method.

Here's how to do this on a pythonic way:

```
def convert_camel_case(string:str)->str:
    # strip before split the sentence
    return ''.join([word.capitalize() for word in string.strip().split()])

print(convert_camel_case("        I     love CHOCOLATE    ."))
```

```
python main.py
ILoveChocolate.
```